# collect the data before the end of the time windows in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use apply function to get unique count. But i want to collect the count when the number of unique data changes.

Code :

```
hashMap       
.keyBy(x => x.hash)       
.timeWindow(Time.minutes(15))
.apply(new DataWindow())
```

But apply function is triggered when the time windows end, how can I get the value more frequently without sliding window.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html) rather than a window. You will want to use key-partitioned [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html) to hold whatever data structure you decide use to track the unique values. You can use either an event time timer or a processing time timer to clear the state every 15 minutes, depending on what kind of time is appropriate to your application.

But if you want to stick with windowing, you could implement a custom [`Trigger`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/Trigger.html). In this case you would need to keep your state in the [partitioned state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/Trigger.TriggerContext.html#getPartitionedState-org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateDescriptor) available on the TriggerContext. Also see [more info about windows and triggers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers).